# How are the equiliberium points of the electric potential characterized?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I am interested in information about the points where the force per charge of a classical electrostatic potential is exactly zero. Loosely speaking, that is to say, if
$$
V(\vec{r};\vec{r}_1,\cdots,\vec{r}_n) = -\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{Z_j}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}_j|}, \qquad Z_j \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
then, where is $\nabla_{\vec{r}} V = 0$? My questions are the following:

- How many zeros does $\nabla_{\vec{r}} V$ have for a given $n$ and collection $\{Z_1,\cdots,Z_n\}$? Formulas or any form of characterization is much appreciated. It seems to me that it should be a collection of isolated points in each case that a zero exists.
- Is the exact location of the zeros known, or is this still an open problem? References are much appreciated.

Comment: I've been looking at these types of problems recently when creating a 3d simulation of electric potential (https://joeiddon.github.io/fields/electric_potential/). Is it the case that your problem is trying to find an $(x,y,z)$ so that $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial z}(x,y,z) = 0$ ? Is so, then one approach would be to use a numerical method, like Newton-Raphson, to find the root.